# Master Spreadsheet, Referenced by presentation spreadsheet - potentially hard?

Tags: vba, excel

I just started a project for a client company and they're needing something kind of unrelated, I'm hoping to get some help with that here.

The situation is this. I have a continually updating "master" spreadsheet located at \ServerA\Folder1\Folder2\MasterSpreadsheet.xlsx. This houses dates ascending left to right on row 219. The dates are ascending(Format mm/dd/yyyy), but not sequential(they skip a few days here and there). The Quantity(row 220) corresponds with dates(row 219). These both start on Column C.

FIRST  "Set" of dates/qty on row 219/220 Column C. 
SECOND "Set" of dates/qty on row 224/225 Column C.

I then have a "Presentation" spreadsheet that will reference the master.
Dates are ascending top to bottom (range 4/25/18 - 12/31/18) in column F and ARE SEQUENTIAL, qty in column G, starting row 9.

So basically what i need is an excel statement that will do this, in whatever fashion is needed.

If the FIRST AND SECOND sets' dates in the date row in MASTER match(could be in column C, all the way to column CZ), the quantities for them both will be added and placed into the correct row (Dates match) in the PRESENTATION spreadsheet.

If the FIRST AND SECOND sets' dates in the date row in MASTER DO NOT match, then they just go to their respective dates on the PRESENTATION spreadsheet.

I hope that was clear enough! Sorry to ask, i can do the rest but this really has me stumped.

Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why you differentiate match or not match for master sets date.
I suggest in sheet PRESENTATION from cell G9 :

```
=SUMIF(MASTER!$C$219:$CZ$219,PRESENTATION!F9,MASTER!$C$220:$CZ$220)+SUMIF(MASTER!$C$224:$CZ$224,PRESENTATION!F9,MASTER!$C$225:$CZ$225)
```

Comment: I was able to use your formula to create what I needed, thank you so much for that! Regarding the differentiation, I just wanted to give as much information as I could, as I did not know what would influence the formula.